# When writing a csv file to Azure Blob storage, can I configure SSIS to represent NULL as BLANK instead of \N?

Tags: ssis, azure-storage, azure-analysis-services

I have an SSIS package that queries an Analysis services database and writes the results to Azure Blob Storage as a csv file.

Package is very simple as below.  My issue is that NULL values are represented as "\N" and I need them to be BLANK.

[image: SSIS Data Flow]

There does not appear to be a NULL handling property in the Azure Blob Destination data flow component. Am I missing something / is there a way to change how this component handles NULL values?

Here is the query:

```
EVALUATE
VAR Customers_csv =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        Customers,
        "CustomerID", Customers[CustomerID],
        "State", Customers[State]
    )
RETURN
    Customers_csv
```

And here is the csv output. The third record is NULL.

```
CustomerID,State
637099,Kentucky
316102,Kentucky
535357,\N
733735,Kentucky
```

Comment: Analysis Services in OLAP mode do not support nulls, not sure about tabular. "\N" looks like a value in your dimension. You can add expression in data flow to replace "\N" with "blank".

Comment: Thanks for the reply Piotr. The \N is only in the SSIS csv file output, it is not present in the AAS cube. Additionally, when I execute the DAX in DAX Studio the "blank" values are indeed blank. The issue is only when SSIS writes the csv file to Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a Derived Column Transformation with the following expression:

```
REPLACE(REPLACENULL([State],""),"\\N","")
```

This will replace `Null`s and `\N` values with a blank string.

---

### Update 1

After searching, it looks like `\N` notation is used to denote NULL value. Check the following links for some workaround:

- [Datafactory V2 Replace "\N" null value with blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005554/datafactory-v2-replace-n-null-value-with-blank)
- [NULLS in File output are \N and I want them to be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621990/nulls-in-file-output-are-n-and-i-want-them-to-be-empty?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hadi but this did not work.  I added a Derived Column transformation in between the OLE DB Source and Azure Blob Destination with the following expression: REPLACE(REPLACENULL([State],""),"\\N",""). However, the file still created \N for the NULL/Blank records.

Comment: @datalore i updated my answer, check the links i provided

Comment: thank you for providing those links.  It appears they only apply to Azure Data Factory and not SSIS.

Comment: @datalore i dont think you can do anything in SSIS